# nested Promise.map() not returning any result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

i am trying to use promises to execute loop inside loop. I want that the inner loop should complete its iteration and the then outer loop should iterate.

for example:-

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
arr2 = [5,6,7,8];

loopOfArr1{
    loopOfArr2{
        //functionality
    }
}
```

I want for each value of arr1, loop of arr2 should get executed. and that will how both loop will finish in sync.

Here is my code using promises:-

```
exports.getAtpagesWeights = function(atpagesDataArray,selectedTagsIds, taggings, callback){
    var atpageData, forHubCount;
    return Promise.map(selectedTagsIds, function(tag, index, count){
        return Promise.map(taggings, function(tagging, index, count){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                var atpageArray = _.filter(atpagesDataArray, function(item){
                    if(tagging.taggable_id == item.id && tagging.tag_id == tag){
                        item = item.toObject();
                        item.rank_weight = tagging.atpages_weight;
                        resolve(item);
                    }
                })
            })
        })       
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        callback(null, result);
    }).catch(function(error){
        callback(error, null);
    })
}
```

But when i check the log, nothing is being printed, can anyone tell where am i going wrong, or is there any better approach?

Comment: I can't see anything asynchronous in your code. What are you using promises for, then? Also, promises and callbacks don't mix very well. Avoid mixing them.

Comment: so if i use forEach instead of promise, how will i be able to get my resulting array, can you please support this with a quick example?

Comment: Not without knowing what the inputs are and what output you are trying to build. But there is nothing asynchronous here. Forget callbacks. Forget promises. Throw all that out. Write a simple function that runs a loop over its parameters, calculates a value and returns that value.

Comment: The way you construct and especially `resolve` your `new Promise` looks really sketchy. What if `atpagesDataArray` is empty or doesn't contain an `item` that matches your condition? And wth are you using `_.filter` for iteration?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding of your code, you want something as simple as this:

```
exports.getAtpagesWeights = function (atpagesData, selectedTagIds, taggings) {
    var atpagesIndex = {},
        atpagesWeights = atpagesData.map(item => {
            var weighted = item.toObject();
            weighted.rank_weight = null;
            atpagesIndex[item.id] = weighted;
            return weighted;
        });

    taggings.filter(t => selectedTagIds.includes(t.id)).forEach(t => {
        atpagesIndex[t.taggable_id].rank_weight = t.atpages_weight;
    });

    return atpagesWeights;
};
```

This would return a flat array of objects directly derived from `atpagesData` items, with `rank_weight` added for selected ones.

As a general rule: asynchronous continuation callbacks exist for one purpose and one purpose only: To deal with asynchronous operations.

Promises are one abstraction level above continuations. Essentially, they are fire-once callbacks with nicer handling, but they are still callbacks at their core.

If your code does not have any asynchronous paths (and your code sample does not look like it) then you don't need that `callback` parameter, and you don't need any promises either. Keep it simple.

Comment: Hey , your answer is pretty crisp and clear, but on using the code you provided, i am getting null value for rank_weight key in array.

Comment: That's it's not working properly is hardly surprising given the fact that you neither provided sample input nor desired output nor any explanation what your code is supposed do do conceptually. So... The same way I analyzed your code to come up with a (likely) simplification, now it's your turn to analyze my code and understand it and apply the principles to your problem.

Comment: "*Callbacks exist for one purpose and one purpose only: To deal with asynchronous operations*" - no. The code in your own answer proves you wrong. Leave the callbacks out of the picture and say that promises are for async operations only, and you'll get my upvote.

Comment: I was referring to the callback parameter the OP was trying to handle in his original code, i.e. "node style" callbacks, the purpose of which is managing async operations. Yes, the statement is too broad if you designate *every* function that's passed as a parameter somewhere a "callback". I don't. I'm not sure how to reword the paragraph, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @bergi Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Read more about _.filter method, your usage is wrong

2) Last Promise is not resolve and not reject, so your console print nothing

3) instead this construction (if it is not promisification)

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     resolve(somthing)
 })
```

better use this construction

```
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(){
        return somthing;
    })
```

4) i add some elegance to your code

```
exports.getAtpagesWeights = function(atpagesDataArray, selectedTagsIds, taggings, callback){
    var atpageData, forHubCount;
    return Promise.map(selectedTagsIds, function(tag, index, count){
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(function() {
                return Promise.filter(taggings, function(tagging) {
                    return tagging.tag_id === tag;
                })
             })
            .then(function(taggings) {
                return Promise.filter(atpagesDataArray, function(item) {
                    return _.chain(taggings)
                        .map('taggable_id')
                        .includes(item.id)
                        .value();
                });
            })
            .then(function(atpagesDataArray) {
                return Promise.map(atpagesDataArray, function(item) {
                    item = item.toObject();
                    item.rank_weight = _.chain(taggings)
                        .find({taggable_id: item.id})
                        .get('atpages_weight')
                        .value();
                    return item;
                });

             })
             .value();
        })       
    })
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        callback(null, result);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        callback(error, null);
    })
}
```

Comment: Looks more like you added another bunch of pointless promises to it…

Comment: @Bergi i made code more readable and determinate. Some Promises truthly is pointless, but i made them special for author, as a example

Comment: OK, elegance is subjective (I'd find a more concise code much better), but I completely agree with your first three points